# Image resizing beside longer text in mobile view

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I have an image beside my text that keeps resizing when I view it in a smaller window, mainly on a mobile view. As you can see with my preview, the shorter text does not resize the image. When I write more, the image is resized. I tried to use flex wrap to wrap around the longer text but it just put the image below the text. Is there something I am simply missing? Thanks in advance for the help.

```css
.content-title {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.icon-img {
  background-image: url(https://cdn2.oceansbridge.com/2017/09/16181826/A-hermit-in-a-ruin.-1650-1668-Jan-Adriaensz.-van-Staveren-oil-painting.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 3.4em;
  height: 3.4em;
}

.content-heading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content-heading">
      <h3 class="content-title">Sample of longer longer longer longer longer longer longer longer longer longer longer longer longer text</h3>
      <div class="icon-img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content-container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content-heading">
      <h3 class="content-title">Sample of shorter text</h3>
      <div class="icon-img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-shrink:0 to the image

Comment: thanks this worked

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `.content-title` a fixed width of `100%` subtracting the `img width`, using `calc`, Like this:

```
width: calc(100% - 3.4em);
```

```css
.content-heading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.content-title {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: black;
  width: calc(100% - 3.4em);
}

.icon-img {
  background-image: url(https://cdn2.oceansbridge.com/2017/09/16181826/A-hermit-in-a-ruin.-1650-1668-Jan-Adriaensz.-van-Staveren-oil-painting.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 3.4em;
  height: 3.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content-heading">
      <h3 class="content-title">Sample of longer longer longer longer longer longer longer longer longer longer longer longer longer text</h3>
      <div class="icon-img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content-container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content-heading">
      <h3 class="content-title">Sample of shorter text</h3>
      <div class="icon-img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Some useful resources:**

- [calc() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc())
- [A Complete Guide to calc() in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-calc-in-css/)